# Node Upgrade to Latest Version

Tags: versioning

1. What is the best way to perform an upgrade to the latest version of substrate for a node with some custom modifications?
2. Is there a way to test that the upgrade hasn't modified the blockchain state in any way?

Comment: Welcome to the community! this is a good set of questions, but please do limit to one at a time, as the answers can be much more targeted https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

with `try-runtime` in `pre` and `post` check
https://docs.substrate.io/v3/tools/try-runtime/

Comment: Thanks! 

For the node upgrade I'm following the guide:
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/docs/Upgrading-2.0-to-3.0.md

However it only covers the upgrade to V3. If I want to get the latest version of contract pallet or the latest monthly upgrade, shall I follow and implement the diffs that happened after V3 release?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you based your project on a version of the [node template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template), you can look at the code diff between some tagged releases there to see what logic changes needed to happen. For example, [this rather large leap from `3.0.0` to `polkadot-v0.9.20`](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/compare/v3.0.0...polkadot-v0.9.20#diff-0ec06ea58bd455f09ce6b3bb4c2c1c0d37bda51c1e1be2151c560c9c973959ecL1).

   > Do keep in mind that if you want to be a *parachain* then at the
   > time of writing, you will often need to stay up to date with the
   > relay chain version you are trying to connect to in real-time.

   If you are intending on updating a *running chain* then you likely have a much more involved job of looking through [storage migrations](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/upgrades/#storage-migrations) that could be required per the pallets you are using from Substrate or other libraries like [ORML](https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library).

---

2. As mentioned in another answer, [`try-runtime`](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/tools/try-runtime/) in `pre` and `post` check can be quite helpful in testing. These is also thinks like [`fork-off-runtime`](https://github.com/maxsam4/fork-off-substrate) that you could consider too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, this is very useful. 

Maybe a simple question, just want a confirmation for my peace of mind. I assume if we upgrade the contracts pallet to support the latest ink! version, the smart contract that have been previously deployed will not be affected in any way?